# vb.net parallel for loop step -1

Tags: vb.net, multithreading, for-loop, parallel.foreach

Is it possible to speed up this code using Parallel.For loop?

I have List of few millions Integer arrays and need to remove all arrays that doesn't meet compare criteria. How can I use multi-threading to speed-up the loop through the List if I need to remove some items from it?

(This is simple code example, real code has more complex criteria checks inside the loop)

```
Function NewList(iList As List(Of Integer())) As List(Of Integer())
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim compareArray As Integer() = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}
    Dim item As Integer()
    For i = iList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        item = iList.Item(i)
        For j = 0 To UBound(compareArray )
            If compareArray(j) > 0 AndAlso Not item.Contains(compareArray(j)) Then
                iList.RemoveAt(i)
                GoTo nextIteration
            End If
        Next j
nextIteration:
    Next i
    Return iList
End Function
```

Comment: You need to make an effort on your own behalf first. Questions of the form *"I want to do X, tell me how"* are off-topic at SO.

Comment: This question is made after my own effort. I try to speed-up the loop and have found that For-Next is faster than For-Each, that variables should be declared outside the loop, that it is possible to use multi-threading for loops. But I don't know how to implement it with Step -1 and with condition that List items will be dynamically deleted inside loop. So I asked directly my question without description of all made efforts.

Comment: With a few million arrays you would probably want to stream them instead of keeping them all in memory (filter them where they are read-in). But if that's okay with you, I would suggest you use parallel for over iList and instead of removing the entry you clear it out through assigning null to it (that does not cause any side effects on the list). After that is done, go through with a single thread backwards through iList and remove all null entries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try something like this (untested):

```
Public Shared Function GetFilteredList(valueList As List(Of Int32()), mustIncludeList As Int32()) As List(Of Int32())
    'Check args
    If (valueList Is Nothing) Then Throw New ArgumentNullException(NameOf(valueList))
    If (mustIncludeList Is Nothing) OrElse (Not mustIncludeList.Any()) Then Return New List(Of Int32())(valueList) 'A new instance to avoid side effects. Could be optimized if not needed
    'Normalize args
    mustIncludeList = (From e In mustIncludeList.Distinct() Where e > 0 Order By e).ToArray() 'Normalize it, remove duplicates and values < 1 (don't do it 1 million times inside the loop)
    'Initialize the filter
    Dim myFilter As Func(Of Int32(), Boolean) = Function(valueArray As Int32())
                                                    'As all of the values must be included we can skip all arrays that are shorter
                                                    If (valueArray Is Nothing) OrElse (valueArray.Length < mustIncludeList.Length) Then Return False
                                                    'Try out if the next line gives a better performance (depends a bit the size of the arrays)
                                                    Dim myValues As New HashSet(Of Int32)(valueArray)
                                                    For Each myMustInclude As Int32 In mustIncludeList
                                                        If (Not myValues.Contains(myMustInclude)) Then Return False
                                                    Next
                                                    Return True
                                                End Function
    'Apply filter and return new list
    Return valueList.AsParallel().Where(myFilter).ToList()
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

EDITED

Thanks to everybody and especially for @Christoph advice to assign "Nothing" to items instead of deleting them and then to clear "Nothing"s from List. Also useful advice to normalize/prepare compare array once outside the loop and not check it millions times [this advice is not implemented here )]

Result speed increased from "minutes" to "seconds"
The following code returns new list in milliseconds with over 2 millions items.

```
Function NewList(iList As List(Of Integer())) As List(Of Integer())
    Dim compareArray As Integer() = {12, 15, 24}

    '//Note that "j" and "item" should be declared inside enclosed Sub 

    'Parallel.For(0, iList.Count - 1, Sub(i)
     Parallel.For(0, iList.Count, Sub(i)
    '//changed upper limit for loop /see comment below code/
                                         Dim j As Integer
                                         Dim item As Integer()
                                         item = iList.Item(i)
                                         For j = 0 To UBound(compareArray)
                                             If compareArray(j) > 0 AndAlso Not item.Contains(compareArray(j)) Then
                                                 iList(i) = Nothing
                                                 GoTo nextIteration
                                             End If
                                         Next j
nextIteration:
                                     End Sub)
    '//parallel.for looped instantly with 2,118,760 items

    '//then removing "Nothing" in usual loop have taken more than a minute,   
    '//so speed-up failed
    'Dim k As Integer
    'For k = iList.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
    '    If iList(k) Is Nothing Then
    '        iList.RemoveAt(k)
    '    End If
    'Next

    '//but using RemoveAll Function cleared List instantly
    iList.RemoveAll(Function(itm) IsNothing(itm))

    Return iList
End Function
```

I've tested Parallel.For approach (more complex than in my own answer) but with passing parameters to be checked to main Function. And result was not always correct. Using @Christoph Function (with AsParallel) - results are ok.

With loop until iList.Count - 1: the last list was not checked, I changed upper loop limit to iList.Count -> and results are correct.
Have to read documentation attentively...(upper loop value is Exclusive)

```
public static System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopResult For (int 
fromInclusive, int toExclusive,
System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelOptions parallelOptions, 
Action<int,System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState> body);
```